# adding country and cities django

Tags: django, python-3.x

i want to add country and cities in forms currently i'm using django-countries for country but i'm gettings this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (country) specified for CustomUser
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DatePicker
from .models import CustomUser
from django_countries.fields import CountryField




class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    CHOICES = (
        (0, 'celebrities'),
        (1, 'singer'),
        (2, 'comedian'),
        (3, 'dancer'),
        (4, 'model'),
        (5, 'Photographer')
    )
    Mobile_Number = forms.CharField(label='Mobile Number', widget= forms.NumberInput)
    Artist_Category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,label = 'something about yourself')
    portfolio = forms.URLField(label = 'enter your portfolio')
    country = CountryField(blank_label = '(select_country)')
    # country = forms.co

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','password','Mobile_Number','Artist_Category','portfolio','country','bio',)
```

models.py: custome user model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
EMAIL_FIELD='email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]

objects=UserManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from main_site.models import artist
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import BookartistForm, ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives,EmailMessage
from django.template import loader
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

## register view

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
     form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        user= form.save()
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        # user = authenticate(request, email=user.email, password=raw_password)
        # if user is not None:
        #     login(request, user)
        # else:
        #     print('user is not authenticated')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'main_site/register.html', {'form':form})
```

...........................................................................................................................

Comment: add code of `CustomUser` model and your views as well.

Comment: i have added in edits

Comment: add country in your CustomUser model.

Comment: I suspect you need "country" Field for CustomUser in models.py

Comment: it working after i added country  to CustomUser model but how can i add cities